# trying to parse two array based on their line numbers

Tags: arrays, perl

I don't know if this is the way to approach the problem I have at hand.
I am attempting to parse out sequences based on their name so an if then statement will do the trick. The problem I am having is associating each array line with its counterpart. (so name to sequence). I would think line numbers of each array would work.

I would do this with a hash but that will not work since you cant have multiple keys with the same name.

sample data

```
>seq1
aaaaa
>seq2
ggggg
>seq1
atatata
```

Script I have so far

```
 open(INPUT_FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
 my @name;
 my @sequence;

 while (my $line = <INPUT_FILE>) {
 if ($line =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
         push @name, $line;
         $line = <INPUT_FILE>;
         push @sequence, $line;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading line by line, then trying to read an extra line.

Can I suggest instead that you should be using `$/` and setting that to `"\n>"`;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n>";

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $name, $sequence ) = split;
    $name=~s/^>//g;   #remove a leading `>`
    print "$name => $sequence\n"; 
}

__DATA__
>seq1
aaaaa
>seq2
ggggg
>seq1
atatata
```

If your "names" are unique you can use a hash to hold the data. But that comes with a caveat - no duplicate keys, and hashes are explicitly unorderd. That doesn't seem to suit your data, so I would suggest instead you can use an array of hashes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = "\n>";

my @sequences; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $name, $sequence ) = split;
    $name=~s/^>//g;   #remove a leading `>`
    push ( @sequences, { name => $name, sequence => $sequence } );
}

foreach my $sequence ( @sequences ) { 
    print $sequence -> {'name'}, " => ", $sequence -> {'sequence'},"\n";
}

print Dumper \@sequences;

__DATA__
>seq1
aaaaa
>seq2
ggggg
>seq1
atatata
```

Thus your structure ends up:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'name' => 'seq1',
            'sequence' => 'aaaaa'
          },
          {
            'name' => 'seq2',
            'sequence' => 'ggggg'
          },
          {
            'sequence' => 'atatata',
            'name' => 'seq1'
          }
        ];
```

As [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) notes in the comments - a hash of arrays may be an option too:

```
#at start of prog
my %sequences;
```

And then in the loop:

```
push ( @{ $sequences{$name} }, $sequence );
```

This will give you:

$VAR1 = {
          'seq2' => [
                      'ggggg'
                    ],
          'seq1' => [
                      'aaaaa',
                      'atatata'
                    ]
        };

Advantages of this are that it'll relate sequences with their respective keys. Disadvantage would be that it loses the ordering that you had in the file (sequences will be in the order that they were seen in the file, but the names won't).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of array of hashes. Im not familiar with the formality of writing it.

Comment: But that was one of the options I was looking at! :) Thanks ~

Comment: Hash of arrays comes to mind, too. `seq1 => [ 'aaaaa', 'atatata' ]`